# Trouble deleting video from YouTube API in c#

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'll apologize in advance for likely missing something obvious, but I've been struggling to find adequate documentation on the .NET c# implementation of the v3 youtube API.  I'm trying to delete a video off the ID that I get back from uploading it after waiting a minute.  This is purely for testing purposes as the final software needs to be significantly more complicated, but I've reduced this problem down to the following code.  The upload runs perfectly, but the delete call at the end throws a 403.  The id string is correct that it's using as I've tried the interface on the API test page. Any thoughts or ideas would be helpful.  thanks a bunch in advance

```
UserCredential credential;

            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "id",
                    ClientSecret = "secret"
                },

                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl },
                "email",
                CancellationToken.None
            );

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });
        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = "test video";
        video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "28"; 
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; 
        var filePath = "path";
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
            await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }

        // uploadID is set globally by response and is correct
        Console.WriteLine(uploadID);

        Thread.Sleep(60000);

        youtubeService.Videos.Delete(uploadID).Execute();
```